# Navigation bar shrinks when position is set to fixed

Tags: html, css

I am currently having an issue where my navigation bar and banner shrink when I set their position to fixed.I have many things like changing z-index,setting its top position to 0,adding auto margin etc, and none of it worked.I hope someone can point me to my mistake.This is my html code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffeecc;
  font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
}

.nav_left {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #258e25;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.banner img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0 15%;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="images/winwin-logo-cover.jpg" alt="winwin logo">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav_left">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php" style="background-color: white; color:black ;font-size:25px;">PROIZVODI</a></li>
          <li><a href="o_nama.php">O NAMA</a></li>
          <li><a href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav_right"></div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

this is how it should look like
[image: without .top{position:fixed}]

this is how it looks like when i put `.top{position:fixed}`
[image: with .top{position:fixed}]

Comment: if you are using `position: fixed` you have to set width of the element otherwise always you will get auto width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set an element to `absolute` or `fixed` position, it will be out of the the normal content flow and trigger the *shrink to fit* feature. You can apply the offsets and width/height to position and recreate the box size you wish to have.

```
.top {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;      /* ADDED */
  top: 0;       /* ADDED */
  width: 100%;  /* ADDED */
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffeecc;
  font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
}

.nav_left {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #258e25;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.banner img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0 15%;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="images/winwin-logo-cover.jpg" alt="winwin logo">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav_left">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php" style="background-color: white; color:black ;font-size:25px;">PROIZVODI</a></li>
          <li><a href="o_nama.php">O NAMA</a></li>
          <li><a href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav_right"></div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `.top` has no width. However, when set to `fixed` it is using the viewport width to calculate the width. You might want to set it to `75%`.

You also might want to set `.container` to `position: relative` so `.top` will relate to its borders.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffeecc;
  font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  position: relative;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 75%;
}

.nav_left {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #258e25;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav_left">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php" style="background-color: white; color:black ;font-size:25px;">PROIZVODI</a></li>
          <li><a href="o_nama.php">O NAMA</a></li>
          <li><a href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav_right"></div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```